# What is powering YouTube?

Tags: web-applications, youtube

I am planning to write an internal large video sharing website.

Is there a resource or article that shows how to plan such a large application development and deployment?

Is there a detailed outline on what YouTube is using as their programming language, video servers, etc...?

Comment: He's asking about more than the language, but the server topology as well. Still not programming related though.

Comment: It is program related enough. Its about software development. Which is enough.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: slightly unrelated question. Did you implement a search feature for your site ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[YouTube Architecture](http://highscalability.com/youtube-architecture):

> 1. Apache
> 2. Python
> 3. Linux (SuSe)
> 4. MySQL
> 5. psyco, a dynamic python->C compiler
> 6. lighttpd for video instead of Apache

Comment: /shrug, I just copied and pasted the link from my browser. Don't have time to be worried about that stuff

Comment: that recipe for success made me chuckle

Answer (score 7):

**YouTube Platform:**

> Apache
>
> Python
>
> Linux
>
> MySql
>
> psyco, a dynamic python->C compiler
>
> lighttpd for video instead of Apache

for more info on [YouTube Architecture](http://highscalability.com/youtube-architecture)

Answer (score 4):

If I can give you one advise: start small!

Large projects have the tendency to take a long time to finish. If you start small, you have some kind of proof of concept first. So you can extend it piece by piece.

Comment: Start small, yes, but plan for scalability. It's very easy to make a small project that is totally unscaleable.

Comment: Of course. You should think of the near future. Even smal steps benefit from a well paved road.

Answer (score 1):

At one point, they were using lighttpd for serving up flash video content.  Their HTTP headers indicate they're using Apache for a lot of pages.  Their help system runs on python, but I think all of Google's help stuff runs on that, so that's no real surprise.  Beyond that, I think it's safe to say there's a lot of in-house technology, no doubt courtesy of Google.

Comment: good answer, its great that you looked into http headers to know who is serving content..!

Answer (score 0):

YouTube was developed in Python.

Answer (score 0):

It's powered by Python:

[image]